# Why I use selenium to upload file and get file not found error?

Tags: python, selenium

This is the code I use . 
I read the selenium link [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html?highlight=files#how-to-upload-files-into-file-inputs). And follow it.

But I get the error like this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: File not found:
C:/MyPython/DownloadGooglePic/save.png
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "http://zhcn.109876543210.com/"

driver.get(url)
# input_field = driver.find_element_by_id("selectfiles")
input_field = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div#container input[type="file"]')
# input_field.send_keys('save.png')
input_field.send_keys('C:/MyPython/DownloadGooglePic/save.png')
submit_upload_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#postfiles')
submit_upload_button.click()

wait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.ok>img')))
print("upload done")
```

**The CSS selector is right here.** 
[image]

Comment: Does `r'C:\MyPython\DownloadGooglePic\save.png'` work?

Comment: @SamChats not work. It's so strange.

Comment: did you replace `/` by \ as suggested ?

Comment: OMG ~ @PRMoureu you are right. tnx a lot for your reply

Comment: @PRMoureu yes adding \\ works